# Can you generate .scss files from .css.map

Tags: css, sass

I was given some files from another developer and was told to make some changes. Within the file structure, there's a .css file and a .css.map file.

I'm relatively new to SASS, but my understanding is that you create a .scss file and use command line: sass --watch style.scss:style.css, which generates the .css.map file and compiles the sass into css.

Is there a way to work backwards with just the .css file and the .css.map file to generate the .scss files, or did the other dev just maybe forget to give me these files?

Comment: They forgave or they didn't want to give you. scss is like source code, you should just modify these files and css is just output. By the way, there is not a real way to generate scss from css + css.map, since several scss can generate the same css, so the backward operation is impossible

Comment: There are a few tools out there that will try and convert it back for you (https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/). But more than likely he just needs to give you the original .scss file. :-)

Comment: Thanks for reaffirming my beliefs!

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The CSS is the output of Sass and you cannot generate the original Sass files from the CSS.**

As stated by [thesassway](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass), source maps (`.css.map`) seek to bridge the gap between higher-level languages like CoffeeScript and Sass and the lower-level languages they compile down to (JavaScript and CSS). Source maps allow you to see the original source (the CoffeeScript or Sass) instead of the compiled JavaScript or CSS while debugging.

*(TL;DR, they are for debugging)*

If you were to edit the CSS output files without using SASS to compile them, the next person who writes in the Sass files and compiles them will overwrite your work.

I'm not sure why the other dev will want you to make changes directly to the CSS output files, but asking them for guidance on what that are expecting you to do won't hurt anyone. :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts! I just wanted to make sure there wasn't anything I was overlooking.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Using Chrome, inspect something on the page, go to "Sources" tab, go to "Page" tab, expand down to the SCSS files generated from the CSS Map (basically the original SCSS files).

Example below is using WordPress and I was in your situation where all I had was the CSS Map file. Just copy and/or save the files one by one into the appropriate folder. Now you have the SCSS files :)

[image]

Comment: It can only work if the .scss files are also available online, which is not always the case. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @probitaille wrong, I only have a CSS and map file, and it aggregates all the sass files that the previous developer was not willing to give me, which are indeed displayed in the Chrome dev tools (also in Firefox too). This solution saved my day, thanks a lot.